# Is there a personal recruiter/agent service in Madrid/Spain?

Tags: spain, job-hunting

Both me and my girlfriend are EU nationals (same country) and recently I moved to Madrid/Spain to work at a big company. For the last several months we are trying to find her a job as well, but given that she has studied Literature and she speaks English and a bit of French, it's proving somewhat difficult and frustrating to be honest.

We have tried applying to all big recruitment/interim companies like Randstad, Manpower, Page, Adecco etc but also private schools for teaching/tutoring etc, however nothing came out of it. We also went to many places/stores/companies and gave her CV, we talked to people, networked as much as possible, but still nothing.

She of course plans to improve her CV by learning Spanish and doing a Masters in something more catchy, but that will take time, so in the meantime what other options are there?

I thought that maybe hiring a personal recruitment agent, who would work with us and help her find something/anything (for a fee of course) would be an option, as they are usually more well connected. So, my question is: **how can I find a personal recruitment agent in Madrid/Spain whom we could hire to help her find a job?**

PS I have already asked Randstad et al, but they don't provide these kind of services and since they work for the employers, they don't really care that much for another candidate.

Comment: Generally, asking for recommendations are off-topic on Expats.SE.  See the [help] for more info, and if you can adjust your question, we can flag it for reopening.

Comment: @MarkMayo I've adjusted and rephrased the question. Is it more suitable now?

Comment: @Surtur I tweaked one line and reopened. Hope that's ok

Comment: @mts agree, but I only had a few min online, so would rather put on hold, have it fixed (by the OP or someone else or even myself later) than have off-topic ones answered.  It's now been fixed, and as I'm on my home PC have had time to edit it as well. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're a native English speaker and don't have much Spanish, teaching English is the obvious thing to do. Right now (the first week of September) is precisely the time to visit the private academies and leave a CV, because they'll be starting up again after the summer and will know either now or within a couple of weeks (some pupils skip September because their parents budget for the books in September and the lessons from October) whether they need any more staff.

Comment: Thanks but we have already tried that. Also, we are not native English/French speakers.

Comment: My point was that I got the impression that you tried at the wrong time of year, but if she's not a native speaker then it is going to be much harder without specific qualifications.

Comment: Oh, ok I see. Perhaps we can try again now. Thanks